# Selecting values without duplicates when conditions meet

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables joining on basis of common one between them and I need one columns each from two tables in the output, when a case condition meets. I see both the columns return their respective records but I see a problem. I see duplicates and I am not sure what is that I am doing wrong here. Attached is the picture[image] with more details.

Comment: Guessing you have multiple rows in typetable for each employee. One for each type.

Comment: Yes, so I want both EmpID and EmpAltID but EmpName only once, and they do have an ID and an alternate ID in the type table.

Comment: It's always the same IDs, so it seems you can simply `select doctable.docnum, emptable.empnum, emptable.empid, emptable.empid as empaltid from ...` and not join the typetable at all. If you can't, please explain why not.

Comment: And are you sure you need outer joins? You want docs even wen they have no related emp or type? Your sample data doesn't suggest that.

Comment: It would be much better by the way to show the tables and query as text, so we could copy and paste and try something with it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I didn't need the outer join. that question lead me to a correction. and the empid and empaltid has types that I need to select to put them into two different columns, so joining was necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use aggregation functions and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  d.docnum DocNumber,
        e.empnam EmpName,
        MAX(CASE
                WHEN t.EmpTypID = '4' THEN e.EmpID
            END) EmpID,
        MAX(CASE
                WHEN t.EmpTypID = '2' THEN e.EmpID
            END) EmpAltID
FROM DocTable d
LEFT JOIN EmpTable e
    ON d.docnum = e.docnum
LEFT JOIN TypeTable t
    ON e.docnum = t.docnum
GROUP BY d.docnum,
         e.empnam
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Group By

```
Select 
........
........
max(CASE
                WHEN t.EmpTypID = '4' THEN e.EmpID
            END) EmpID,
.........
GROUP BY d.docnum,
         e.empnam
;
```